# ASP MVC EF - binding request object to context object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hello I have a problem with binding requests object to context object. I show by example:

```
class Car {
 public int Id{get; set;}
 public string Name{get; set;}
 public User Owner{get; set;}
}

class User{
 public int Id{get; set;}
 public string Name{get; set;}
 public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars{get; set;}
}

//CarController
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Create(Car car){
     DbContext.Cars.Add(car);
     DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

$http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'http://localhost/project/api/car/create',
            data: {
                Name: "Audi",
                Owner: { Id: 3 }
            }
        })
```

When I run this code, to database will be saved car and created new user (with incremented (different) id). I would like to dont create new user, but add foreign key. I know why it behaves like this, context doesnt know my User object. How can it be solved? Thanks

Comment: i can see that you didn't assigned any user object to car object. So its creating new user. In order to assign foreign key first retrieve the user and assign it to car before inserting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code. I am assuming user id as 1 you can give as your requirement

1.Update your car class to have owner id property for foreign key

```
class Car {
 public int Id{get; set;}
 public string Name{get; set;}
 public int OwnerId {get;set;}
 [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
 public User Owner{get; set;}
}
```

2.The write below code to assign owner to car

```
car.OwnerId = 1
DbContext.Cars.Add(car);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, i was afraid of that. It is any possibility, how save without preview load user? My object (here is Car) has many foreign keys, i dont want load all objects due to foreign keys.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it. It should work